# AndroidStudioのデザインエディターが表示されなくなったことに関して

Tags: android-studio

アンドロイドスタジオを使い始めて一週間くらいの初心者です。今回デザインエディターが表示されなくなってしまいました。デザインエディターにはこう表示されています。

```
design editor is unavailable until a successful build
```

イベントログでは

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'exe' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
            Consult IDE log for more details
```

と表示されています。

```
build syncにはCould not get unknown property 'exe' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
Open File
```

と表示されていて、Open Fileをひらいたものがこちらの画像です。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

デザインエディターが表示されないため困っています。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 該当ソースは、イメージを載せるのもよいですが、加えてテキストとして載せたほうがよいと思います。ちなみに `exe.anko_version` の部分は何かを参考にして足したのでしょうか？？

Answer (score 2):

```
exe.anko_version
```

を

```
ext.anko_version
```

に変更してみて下さい。Gradleの拡張プロパティの指定は`ext`ですね。

[ここ](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko)に以下のように記載されています。

> Make sure that you have the $anko_version settled in your gradle file at the project level:
>
> `ext.anko_version='0.10.6'`

Comment: extにすることで改善されました。しかし、新しい問題が出てきたので、別の質問を作らせていただきます。